# ¿Como se hace un 'array' de 'hashes' en Perl 6?

Tags: raku

Quiero crear un 'array' de 'hashes' en Perl 6. Por ejemplo:

```
use Test;
plan 1;

my @esperado = [ 
                {A => 1, B => 2}; 
                {C => 3, D => 4}; 
            ];

my %hash1 = A => 1, B => 2;
my %hash2 = C => 3, D => 4;

my @resultado;

@resultado.push( %hash1, );   # o @resultado.push( [%hash1], )
@resultado.push( %hash2, );   # o @resultado.push( [ %( C => 3, D => 4)], );

is-deeply @resultado, @esperado, 'crear array de hashes';
```

Esto resulta en lo siguente:

```
1..1
not ok 1 - crear array de hashes

# Failed test 'crear array de hashes'
# at test.p6 line 17
# expected: [{:A(1), :B(2)}, {:C(3), :D(4)}]
#      got: [:B(2), :A(1), :D(4), :C(3)]
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1
```

En Perl 5, se puede usar una referencia a un hash como un elemento de un array. ¿Hay algo similar en Perl 6?

Comment: No entiendo exactamente por qué, pero funciona con `@resultado.push(%hash1, %hash2)`, y también con `@resultado.push( { %hash1 } ); @resultado.push( { %hash2 } );`. A ver si alguien lo puede explicar...

Comment: @TomFenech Yo usaba una versión vieja. Funciona bien con una versión mas reciente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con la última versión de Rakudo (2015.12-117), me sale un resultado correcto:

```
1..1
ok 1 - crear array de hashes
```

La explicación sobre las referencias la tienes en https://doc.perl6.org/language/5to6-nutshell#Reference_creation

Comment: ¡Gracias! Olividé averiguar si fuera problema de una versión vieja. No hay problema con Rakudo Star 2015.11.